# App Pool Id in IIS_IUSRS and IIS_IUSRS read access to NTFS but 403

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

In a Server 2012 VM on Azure.

- I created a new Application Pool, called Spandex.
- I created a new, empty website called Spandex with default "passthrough" auth.
- I created a new empty folder c:\Website Roots\Spandex
- I created Default.htm in the folder with some content.
- I added IIS_IUSRS to the NTFS permissions, read access.
- I added IIS APPPOOL\Spandex to the IIS_IUSRS group.
- I rebooted.

I get a 403 accessing from remote.

I get 403.14 Forbidden when attempting to access ~/Default.htm from the local VM.

> A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Default.htm is listed in the Default Document settings list (inherited) and has IIS_IUSRS read.

In IIS Man, under Basic Settings, Test Settings fails the Authorization check. However, this fails for the Default Website, too, and that comes up fine in the browser.

What on Earth have I missed??

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

It's that *@~$%ng moronic default Windows behaviour of pretending critical information doesn't exist, even on SERVERS, like hiding file extensions. I mean, who needs to known a file extension?

I had created `Default.htm.txt`

Something deeply wrong with the ivory towered Windows team of the last 10 years.